# Need help getting images to stack inside a div

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a series of images to stack one on top of each other inside a div and I need some help. The div is set up in CSS to be `450px` wide and the top picture is always that width. The images that follow will vary in size and need to flush right with `36px` of padding on the right side.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<div id="photos">
    <img style="position:relative; top:0px; width:450px" src="images/picture1.jpg" />
    <img style="position:relative; top:0px; float:left; left:100px" src="images/picture2.jpg" />
    <img style="position:relative; top:0px; float:right; right:36px" src="images/picture3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Unfortunately the bottom two photos want to sit next to each other. Even if I put a break after the second picture, they remain in the same place.

I tried setting the div to `display: block`, but there was no change.

Comment: When you say "stack one on top of the other", do you mean literally overlaying each other, or each following the last in a column?

Comment: Could you provide a picture of how you want them to stack?

Answer (score 2):

If you want them to stack, use inline-block
http://jsfiddle.net/jax29/

css

```
#photos{
width:450px;
}

#photos img{
display:inline-block;
}

#photos img:nth-child(n+2){
margin-right:36px;
float:right;
}
```

html

```
<div id="photos">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/siHvwSU.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/siHvwSU.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/siHvwSU.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'll upvote for the artwork alone... ok, I guess also because it works, but that is secondary.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you want, but if you want the images stacked vertically and never horizontally, you could set `text-align: right;` on the parent div rather than using `float: right` to align the images.

If you want to use `float: right;` try adding `clear: both;` on each image. That way, they won't want to jump up next to the previous image. using `float` tells subsequent elements to display next to the floated element.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that solves most of the issues. The `float: right;` seems to have been the culprit. There will be instances where I do want two images that will fit on a single row to do so flushed to the top of the largest image. I'm trying to do that now but the smaller image is flushing to the bottom of the larger one. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you tell me how you are getting the two images to display next to each other? It could have to do with your method.

Comment: here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CpN2X/) to an example of how one might achieve what I think you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This should fit your requirements.

```
<div id="photos">
    <img src="images/picture1.jpg" /><br />
    <img src="images/picture2.jpg" style="padding-right:36px;"><br />
    <img src="images/picture3.jpg" style="padding-right:36px;">
</div>

#photos {
    width: 450px;
    text-align: right;
}
```